# Trying to call HTTPS Api in Xamarin Android and i am receiving receiving Exception (The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception)

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a Mobile Application built in Xamarin Forms using HTTP API's which was working perfectly fine but when the HTTP API's moved to HTTPS, I started receiving SSL exception

[Project Properties Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkaAq.jpg)

[Android Properties Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5XGZ.jpg)

[Exception Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyOuC.jpg)

Is there any possible way to resolve this?

```
private HttpClient GetClient(HttpClientHandler handler = null)
{
    try
    {
        IProxyInfoProvider _proxyInfoProvider = DependencyService.Get<IProxyInfoProvider>();
        HttpClientHandler handlerClient = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            Proxy = _proxyInfoProvider.GetProxySettings()
        };
        handlerClient.UseProxy = true;
        //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
        // handlerClient.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handlerClient
        return client;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

I am unable to use Service Point Manager or Server Certificate Custom Validation Callback because the project is in PCL format and Targeting ".NET Framework 4.5"

Comment: Why are you using PCL?  .NET Standard has been available for quite a while

Comment: We are aware that this can be resolved in .NET Standard but wanted to know if there is any solution to this in PCL, because it will require time to convert the project to .net standard

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the Android SSL/TLS Implementation setting from "Managed TLS 1.0" to "Default (Native TLS 1.2+)". This is the setting you should be using according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/http-stack?tabs=windows).

> April, 2018 – Due to increased security requirements, including PCI compliance, major cloud providers and web servers are expected to stop supporting TLS versions older than 1.2. Xamarin projects created in previous versions of Visual Studio default to use older versions of TLS.
> In order to ensure your apps continue to work with these servers and services, you should update your Xamarin projects with the **Android HttpClient** and **Native TLS 1.2** settings shown below, then re-build and re-deploy your apps to your users.

Comment: SSL/TLS was set to Default but that didn't work either but after some research a thread helped to solve the problem, Thanks.

Comment: Could you please post the link here to answer? I am facing same issue now.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1
Add a class in Android Project

```
namespace Mobility.Droid.Dependency
{
    public class HttpClientHandlerCustomValidation : System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler
    {
        public HttpClientHandlerCustomValidation() : base()
        {
            ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertficate;
        }
        static bool ValidateServerCertficate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Step 2
You will have to edit the Android.csProj file and edit AndroidHttpClientHandlerType, Add this tag for both debug property group and release property group.

```
<AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>Mobility.Droid.Dependency.HttpClientHandlerCustomValidation, Mobility.Droid</AndroidHttpClientHandlerType>
```

Step 3
You will have to remove the handler client in the custom client you generated
do this

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
        return client;
```

instead of

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handlerClient)
        return client;
```

@brendanzagaeski comment from [this thread](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/3682) helped solve this issue